# Can't align JFileChooser to the left of BorderLayout.NORTH

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfilechooser, border-layout

I have a window with a JFileChooser and a JTextArea.
The JFileChooser is in the NORTH part of the BorderLayout.
The JTextArea is in the CENTER part of the BorderLayout.

I would like to align to the left ALL my JFileChooser, but it won't move like I want and stay CENTERED.
Furthermore, I would like my JFileChooser take all the length of my window.

**EDIT**

**Here is the main code**

```
public class MainServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ServerBoard frame=new ServerBoard(1000, 500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
     }
}
```

**Here is the window code**

```
public class ServerBoard extends JFrame
{
    private JButton startserver;
    private JButton senddata;   
    private JButton sendgps;
    private JTextArea messagearea;

    public ServerBoard(int l, int h)
    {
        super("ServerBoard");
        this.initialize();
        this.setSize(l,h);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void initialize()
    {
        // Define a panel
        Container c=this.getContentPane();

        this.messagearea=new JTextArea(40,60);      

        c.add(this.createNorth(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        c.add(messagearea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JPanel createNorth()
    {
        JPanel panelnorth=new JPanel();

        JToolBar toolbarnorth=new JToolBar();
        panelnorth.add(toolbarnorth);

        this.startserver=new JButton("START SERVER");
        startserver.addActionListener(new ServerBoardListener());
        toolbarnorth.add(startserver);

        this.senddata=new JButton("SEND DATA");
        senddata.addActionListener(new ServerBoardListener());
        toolbarnorth.add(senddata);

        this.sendgps=new JButton("SEND GPS FRAME");
        sendgps.addActionListener(new ServerBoardListener());
        toolbarnorth.add(sendgps);

        return panelnorth;  
    }
}
```

**Here is my window**

[image]

I really really want to use this JFileChooser. Can you help me please ?

In advance thank you a lot for the answers.

Comment: When you say `here is the code`, you should provide a runnable code where we just have to copy paste then you'll get fasters and better answers!

Comment: Hi @nachokk, yes, sorry, I've edit my question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply nest your JPanels. Create a new JPanel, say called northPanel, that uses a BorderLayout, and add it to the main window in the BorderLayout.NORTH position, and then add your JFIleChooser to this northPanel JPanel in its BorderLayout.WEST position.

Option 2: give the northPanel a BoxLayout that is oriented along the line axis, add the JFileChooser, and add glue.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I didn't even thought about this methods ! I really stupid... I'll try it :)

But are these methods are somewhat heavy, isn't it ? There is no other functions for that ?

Comment: @Tofuw: no, this all uses what I'd consider "light-weight" code and components. What other "functions" could you possibly mean?

Comment: Ok, that's good so :) By other "functions" I mean something like "setPosition(LEFT)". But it seems there are no other methods. Thanks to you again Hovercraft !